# Retrofit REST client for Android and Java does not terminate

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I am investigating the Retrofit REST client for Android and Java.

Using a standard Java project within Eclipse I am using @POST with void return type.

Making Asynchronous calls.

Everything works as expected, however my test main method never terminates. I have to manually stop each test execution.

What do I need to do (or stop doing) so that my tests terminate automatically?

Here's my java code.

```
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class Android {

    private static final RestAdapter mRestAdapter =
        new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/resources/registrations")
            .build();

    public static void main(final String... args) {

        final AndroidRegister androidRegister =
            mRestAdapter.create(AndroidRegister.class);

        Callback<Void> callback = manufactureCallback();

        androidRegister.androidRegisterInterface(
            new RegistrationIdJson("1111-2222-3333-4444"), callback);    
    }

    private static Callback<Void> manufactureCallback() {
        return new Callback<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void failure(final RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                System.out.println("retrofitError-->"
                    + retrofitError.getLocalizedMessage() + "<---");
            }

            @Override
            public void success(final Void returning,
                                final Response response) {
                System.out.println("-->" + returning + "<--->"
                    + response.getStatus() + "<---");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Retrofit uses a non-daemon thread pool with a 60s core pool timeout. Very, very rarely do you want to use Retrofit's async `Callback` behavior in this manner.

If you are simply testing, you can call `setExecutors` on the `RestAdapter.Builder` and pass a synchronous executor as the first argument and `null` for the second. This will allow you to use the asynchronous API but get synchronous behavior in your tests.

And a synchronous executor, if you don't know how to make one:

```
public final class SynchronousExecutor implements Executor {
  @Override public void execute(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
  }
}
```