# Retrofit doesn't terminate

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

I am learning retrofit 2.1 using Java 
I am sending a post request asynchronously but even on successful execution of onresponse method the program doesn't terminate for like 1 - 1.5 minutes. Testjson.java is the executor file, It references two classes - **RegisteredUser.java** and **ApiCLient.java**. Apiclient.java is an interface includes the post form request and RegisteredUser.java(not included) is created through jsonschema2pojo, It contains two fields status and message and getter setter functions.

### **TestJson.java**

```
    public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String phone = "9717014775";
        String email = "sanjay.kumar75033@gmail.com";

        final String BASE_URL = "http://myapponline.in/API/";


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        ApiClient client =  retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);



        Call<RegisteredUser> userCall = client.getUser(phone, email,"users");

        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<RegisteredUser>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisteredUser> arg0,
                    Response<RegisteredUser> arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 RegisteredUser user =   arg1.body();

                 if(user.getStatus().equals("1"))
                     System.out.println("alredy Registered");
                 else System.out.println("not registered");



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisteredUser> arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println(arg1);
            }
        });




    }


      }
```

**APIClient.java**

---

```
     public interface ApiClient {

      @FormUrlEncoded
      @POST("checkuserexists.php")
        Call<RegisteredUser> getUser(@Field("phone") String    phone,@Field("email") String email,@Field("usertype") String usertype);

     }
```

Comment: Please include your code so we can examine and assist.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I edidted the code, I dont how to do this in comment. I dont know much about posting question.

Comment: There is a similar question on stack overflow <a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340780/retrofit-rest-client-for-android-and-java-does-not-terminate"> similar question</a>

Comment: How are you running this?  You don't normally use `public static void main` in Android.

Comment: @ishmaeMakitla I am running it on Java . I am just trying to learn retrofit